# unable to override laravel 5.4 default field name in login Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

using below given code i want to override laravel default fields and table name   with my custom by this code my table name is overridden but field name "email" is not overriding by "userEmail"

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'User';

    protected $email = 'userEmail';//overriding  laravel default field name



    public $fillable = [
        'name', 'userEmail', 'password',
    ];
    public static  $fillable2 = [
        'name', 'userEmail', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


}
```

when using above code getting following error from laravel
[image]

using laravel Authentication Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this error encountered while auth attempt ? or something else ?

Comment: share your controller codes so we know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: are you using Auth::attempt($request->only(['userEmail','password'])); ??

Comment: Can you include the error starting `SQLSTATE` in your question as text also please, to make it searchable

Comment: @SagarGautam i did not use auth attempt

Comment: @Demonyowh no i didn't

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed so what is the code where this error is encountered ?

Comment: it is default laravel auth implementation which i create by calling this command (php artisan make:auth)

Answer (score 0):

You able to override the email field to userEmail the by putting the following in `Auth/LoginController.php`

```
public function username()
    {
        return 'userEmail';
    }
```

When authenticating by custom method  , you need to change username to `userEmail`,

```
Auth::attempt( array('userEmail' => $username, 'password' => $password) )
```

Comment: where do i need to write this line of code in which file can u please mention location

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed which version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: i have Auth/AuthController.php i am using laravel 5.4  not having Auth/LoginController.php so what ??

Comment: using laravel 5.4 @suresh

Comment: I hope you are upgraded from v5.2 to 5.4. `Auth/LoginController.php` avialable from v5.3

Comment: so you mean what i want to do is not possible in laravel 5.4

Comment: yep .. But you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483643/laravel-5-override-login-function Ensure you are using v5.4 . Becuase  ` Trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`, was removed from 5.3

Comment: so what i can do for laravel 5.4

Comment: Actually, I gave the solution for v5.4. I hope you have to look for v5.2

Comment: no i was looking for laravel 5.4 but the problem is that laravel hardcode the table name and fields name because of which we can not override them

Answer (score 0):

In your `AuthController` add a property named `username` set to your desired field name.

```
protected $username = 'userEmail';
```

Comment: Behaving ab normally error gone but with right password i am unable to login now

Comment: no no error validation msg just redirect on same page with out error msg

Comment: How did you stored the password.

Comment: If you are using a custom hashing function you need to override `postLogin` in your `AuthController` and handle the authentication. It's not recommended to use `md5` for storing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

This another version of my answer, it will surely works  if you have **laravel 5.2**

Add the following method

```
public function loginUsername()
        {
            return 'userEmail';
        }
```

To the

> AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function loginUsername()
    {
        return 'userEmail';
    }

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,userEmail',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'userEmail' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }


}
```

Don't forget to modify the `validator` and `create` methods according to the new field name.

Note: need to change login.balde.php and register.balde.php which are came along with laravel5.2

login.balde.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('userEmail') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="userEmail" value="{{ old('userEmail') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('userEmail'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('userEmail') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

register.balde.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```